# VMware CPU Utilization on a particular host

Tags: vmware

We are working on VMware and HA and DRS are enabled on a cluster. We want to set CPU threshold for every host i.e. if cpu utilization goes above 80% vm's move automatically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Details

You receive an event message when the number of phisycal cpu on the host exceeds their limit.

This occurs when clients register more cpu on an ESXi host than the host can support.

Impact

If the limit is exceeded, the management agent is at risk of running out of system resources. Consequently, VMware vCenter Server might stop managing the corresponding ESXi host.

Solution

To ensure management functionality, restrict the number of Pcpu to the limit indicated by the VMkernel.Boot.maxPCPUS property of the ESXi host.

To lower the value of maximum number of allowed registered pcpu:

Edit the VMkernel.Boot.maxPCPUS variable by selecting the host in vCenter Server.
Open the Configuration tab and select Advanced Options in the Software box.
Expand the VMkernel option and click Boot.
Alter the value in the text box to the right of the VMkernel.Boot.maxPCPUS variable.

Hope to be useful ;)

Comment: Maybe i was not clear in my question as i just want to set threshold on cpu utilization like if any host's cpu utilization goes above 80% drs should automatically move some vm's to other host so that cpu utilization on that particular host again come down to 80%. Is it possible to do in host level?